# How to insert a text in all lines of a column in a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to insert a text in a range of lines of a specific column of a csv file like [2:], I already searched other question like this on the internet, but none worked to me.

Example:

```
"File before I insert text"
NAME, AGE
 , 2
 , 3
 , 4
 , 5
```

"File after I insert a text"

```
NAME, AGE
henrique , 2
henrique , 3
henrique , 4
henrique , 5
```

my code:

```
header = ["Name", "Age"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header)
var=df.shape[0]
df.loc[var:, 'Name'] = 'henrique'
df.to_csv("stackoverflow.csv", 
          index=False)
```

Comment: Just `df['Name'] = 'henrique'` would work.

Comment: This didn´t work to me, nothing was inserted in the column.

Comment: @QuangHoang I updated my question with more informations about my problem.

Comment: @QuangHoang I need to write a text in a specific column in a range like [df.shape[0] : ]